# SMSS will start for one user, but not another?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

We have a SQL Server 2012 and SMSS 2012 installed.  The C:\ recently ran out of space due to a misconfiguration, and now we have 1 user who cannot start `SMSS` they receive the error:

```
"Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall application"
```

However when I login with my domain admin account, I can start SMSS perfectly fine.  We are both in the server `Administrator` group.  I have also "repaired" the SQL Server tools (which includes the SMSS app) on the box with no change in behavior.

Is there a log file somewhere I can check to see why `SMSS` will not start for this one user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something in their documents\user data profile got corrupted. If you've fixed the space issue, then I suggest running a repair on the application (or installing a newer version - you can manage SQL Server 2012 with SSMS 2014 or newer, and it's free - [installation instructions in this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/73919/1186)). However it may still end up being hosed because of that user's profile - if so, as a next step, you could back up their files and re-create their profile (though I do concede that this will force you to lose a lot of their other settings etc).

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I've run the repair and still same results.  (Works for me and not him).  Im going to delete his user profile and see what happens.  I'll update in a few with results.

Comment: Next would be upgrading to SSMS 2014 (and optionally just removing SSMS 2012). In fact I might try that before messing with the user's profile.

Comment: Deleting the users profile did the trick.  Thank you for the assistance!