# Remote connection to DB instance from fresh formatted system?

Tags: sql-server, configuration

I have 1 win7prof  fresh system. Now I want to connect to a DB instance remotely via sqlcmd/any other way. My req is  to connect and execute select query? is there any method/software needed to be installed in fresh win7prof system to access the instance.? kindly let me know what to do for access and use manipulation operations ?

Answer (score 2):

I checked this out and the latest available standalone for SQL Server Management Studio is a 2008 version [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593).

Thanks to @AaronBertand, the process of obtaining the SQL Server Management Studio 2014 involves clicking the download button for the full SQL Server Express 2014 and then you will be offered a choice of only downloading the Studio (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twNOv.png) - with thanks again to Aaron Bertrand). Detailled instructions available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver2014express.aspx).

If you just want a command line client, then check out [this](http://www.verboon.info/2012/03/how-to-get-the-sqlcmd-standalone-for-microsoft-sql-server-management/) post.

Comment: There should be a standalone installer for SQL Server Management Studio Express 2014 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299) or for 2012 SP2 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351). These will be better than 2098 for two reasons: (1) they are full functional (lots of restrictions in the 2008 version) and (2) if the OP is managing any versions > 2008, the 2008 client will not be capable of performing some tasks that it isn't aware of...

Comment: Maybe I haven't understood how Microsoft do things (wouldn't be the first time :-) ), but your link gives the entire SQL Server Express - I couldn't see a Management Studio Express 2014 download on that page (2008 Management Studio is available there). Do you have to start the process of downloading the 2014 Express, then to be offered the Management Studio choice as a standalone?

Comment: No, see http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/73919/1186

Comment: So, it appears that Microsoft does indeed make life a bit counterintuitive. They've decided not to release the Management Studio as a separate download. However, it can be installed separately on launching the SQL Server Express download. I'll update and clarify my answer. Thanks for that.

Comment: Well, that's not quite accurate. When you click Download, there is an option to select just a Management Studio installer ([see this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/twNOv.png)). The setup program, though, is generic, and doesn't *know* that the package is meant to be Management Studio only.